# atmosphereJS is not picking up readme.md file?

Tags: meteor, atmosphere.js

I created a package and hosted it on gitlab. I have set the README.md on pakage.js (I am using the default one, I just replaced the text inside README.md), but the text inside README.md does not seem to reflect on the package overview. Please tell me what is wrong.

This is the contents of my `package.js`

```
    Package.describe({
      name: 'myname:mypackage',
      version: '0.0.2',
      summary: 'mypackage',
      git: 'https://gitlab.com/zeitgeist/mypackage.git',
      // By default, Meteor will default to using README.md for documentation.
      // To avoid submitting documentation, set this field to null.
      documentation: 'README.md'
    });
```

Comment: Hey thanks. Interestingly enough, the readme.md was reflected just now. Last time I pushed was  Apr 5. Weird. I thought the thing would reflect immediately.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default like you have on the comments, if you have the `README.md` on the root of the project, it will take it and use the [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/).

But since you are using the `documentation:'README.md'` field.

You should put the path-to-readme, on the following syntaxis.

```
documentation: 'path/to/my/readme.md',
```

See more on the [Atmosphere DOCS](https://atmospherejs.com/i/publishing)

So if you have the README.md on the root of the project, just set this field to null or delete it.

```
Package.describe({
      name: 'myname:mypackage',
      version: '0.0.2',
      summary: 'mypackage',
      git: 'https://gitlab.com/zeitgeist/mypackage.git',
      // By default, Meteor will default to using README.md for documentation.
      // To avoid submitting documentation, set this field to null.
      documentation: null //or delete it
    });
```